# Why is Chrome reporting outdated response headers?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, http-headers

Using TomCat to serve a web site.  Often, when I update the site, Chrome gets confused about cache, and continues to use old pages in cache even though newer ones are available.  This seems to be based on a more fundamental problem that Chrome is not getting the latest response headers from the server either, and that seems to prevent any ability to control the cache.

I chose a javascript file, made a small modification to change the date of the file in the file system.  I then refetched the page in both Mozilla and Chrome.  Mozilla appears to run correctly: the server returns 200 and most importantly the Last-Modified header says the same thing as the timestamp on the file.

However, Chrome, I get the most curious response.  It claims to get a 200 response, but it does NOT refresh its cache.  According to Chrome, the Last-Modified header is from several months ago!  I am using TomCat in very basic mode of serving files -- no special code from me involved.  I really don't believe that TomCat is returning different headers to Chrome.

It looks like Chrome never even asks the server.  I can't find any record on the server of a request for that file.  It appears that Chrome is simply sitting with the cached file, reporting the old headers from the fetch it did a couple days ago.  It is not requesting the headers from the server, and it is not being sent a 304.  It simply does not call the server.

I did a third fetch from a HTTP testing tool which reports the headers returned.  The headers retrieved this way matches the headers reported by Mozilla, but NOT the headers reported by Chrome.  Chrome seems to have cached the header responses from earlier, and because of that is NOT downloading the modified file.

Even the ETag header is different.  Mozilla and the test tool report an ETag header of W/"464427-1517160284971" however Chrome claims that the response included the ETag value of W/"464400-1511152262000".  I simply don't believe that the server returned that value.

I have been struggling with users having to clear the Cache on Chrome and it is getting to be a *real problem*.  Is there any way I can FORCE Chrome to refresh the cache when the pages are modified without ruining the network performance for everyone.

Here are Mozilla Headers

[image: headers reported by Mozilla]

Here are the Chrome "reported" headers

[image: headers reported by Chrome]

Here is the Test Tool Headers.

[image: headers reported by HTTP test tool]

Comment: It says "from memory cache". Do you know if Chrome is actually making the request?

Comment: No.  It seems that Chrome does not make a request at all to the server.  Mozilla will request and get a 304 response.  But it seems that Chrome does not even ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be to add the option `must-validate` to the `Cache-Control` response header.   Without this header, and without other specific time based commands to release the cached file, Chrome will cache the file forever, and will not go back to the server and check whether there is a newer file.

By default, Apace TomCat does not include `must-validate` in the `Cache-Control` header on the response.  That is why using the default settings on TomCat, Chrome will cache files forever.  It is strange, because it looks like it fetched the file, but it does not, and it reports the HTTP response (200) from when it retrieved the file days ago.

In TomCat, the only way to add a header to the response, is to write a class that does that on every request.  Here is a suitable class:

```
public class HeaderCorrectingFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
        //nothing to destroy
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

And here is the setting in WEB.XML to cause it to be invoked

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>HeaderCorrectingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.example.HeaderCorrectingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>HeaderCorrectingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is a [blog post](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/caching-for-chrome/) that fills in the details on how to make a